# Does Less have support for Custom Elements?

Tags: less, web-component

Does Less have any support for the Web Components Custom Elements spec? (http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/ or more accessible http://www.x-tags.org/docs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less does not put any restrictions on used selectors/properties/values as long as they meet the base CSS grammar, e.g. the following Less code:

```
whatever {
    whatever-else: I dont care;
    &:tlhIngan(Hol)[DaH="mojaq-mey-vam"] {
        color: pitch black #2;
    }
}
```

results in this CSS:

```
whatever {
  whatever-else: I dont care;
}
whatever:tlhIngan(Hol)[DaH="mojaq-mey-vam"] {
  color: pitch black #2;
}
```

Additionally there's special escaping syntax to pass just *any* characters through (i.e. `~"whatever-'characters'-here//**\@\$^%\n"`).

So to answer the question: Yes, Less supports custom elements as well as any future standard elements unless they introduce a new incompatible syntax.